# Why directory is created by hostPath with no type specified?

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage, persistent-volumes

According to [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/?spm=a2c63.p38356.0.0.28874dcbfWkCRx#hostpath), we should specify `type: DirectoryOrCreate` if we want to create directory on the host. The default option is **"no checks will be performed before mounting the hostPath volume"**.

However, I am seeing directory gets created on host even when no type is specified:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: busybox-user-hostpath
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox-user-local-storage1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox-user-local-storage1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: busybox:latest
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "while :; do echo $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') deployment1 >> /home/test.txt; sleep 5 ; done"]
          volumeMounts:
          - name: busybox-hostpath
            mountPath: /home
      volumes:
        - name: busybox-hostpath
          hostPath:
                path: /home/maintainer/data
```

`/home/maintainer/data` directory did not exist before running the pod. After deployment, I can see the directory is created. This goes against the documentation unless I am missing something. I was expecting the pod should crash but I can see the files are created. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that goes back in time, before type was even implemented for hostPath volume. When unset should just go and default directly to create an empty directory, and it's a backward compatible implementation, because no one had the option to add **type** and forcing an error when it's not defined would have broken all previously created pods without it. You can take a look into the actual design-proposal: https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/main/storage/volume-hostpath-qualifiers.md#host-volume

The design proposal clearly specifies that "***unset** - If nothing exists at the given path, an empty directory will be created there. Otherwise, behaves like exists*"

Comment: Ah! that explains. But I do think the documentation is misleading or at least they should have clarified in the DirectoryOrCreate type. Although they say "Empty string (default) is for backward compatibility", it is not clear what that compatibility would be as no further information given.

Comment: I think the description is quite clear. "**Empty string (default) is for backward compatibility, which means that no checks will be performed before mounting the hostPath volume.**" - it states that if you don't specify type, no additional checks will be performed (compared with the other values that `type` can get) and will not fall under the rule of the other values of `type`. The key of the description lies in `before mounting the hostPath volume.`.